# SwiftUI/ARKit issue: ARSCNViewDelegate.renderer does not trigger on first load on iOS16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, arkit, ios16

Hi fellow stackers and keen eyed developers,

facing an issue where as the **renderer of ARSCNViewDelegate does not trigger when SwiftUI view, ARDelegate are initialized in iOS 16**. It appears to work just fine on iOS17 beta(aka renderer functions are called and subsequently my trackDistance() func); what could be the problem here? Any feedback is very much appreciated.

Here the description of my setup:

I have a **SwiftUI** view that includes my **ARDelegate** and displays my **UIViewRepresentable**:

```
struct PersonTrackerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var arDelegate = ARDelegate()
    
    var body: some View {
                VStack {
                  ...
                 }
                 .overlay(
                    HStack{
                       ARViewRepresentable(arDelegate: arDelegate)
                    })
                   ...
         } // end of body
}
```

my **UIViewPresentable** is implemented as:

```
struct ARViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let arDelegate:ARDelegate
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let arView = ARSCNView(frame: .zero)
        arDelegate.setARView(arView)
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

and here my **ARDelegate** impl:

```
class ARDelegate: NSObject, ARSCNViewDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var someNode = SCNNode()
    var arSCNView: ARSCNView?
...
    func setARView(_ arView: ARSCNView) {
        self.arSCNView = arView
                
        guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else { return }
        guard self.arSCNView != nil else { return }
        let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
        arView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        
        arView.delegate = self
        arView.scene = SCNScene()
        addNode()
    }
...
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        // do some node transform stuff
        ...

        trackDistance()
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        // do some node transform stuff
        ...
        trackDistance()
    }
}
```

**The Problem: renderer funcs and subsequently trackDistance() are never called when the SwiftUI view loads the first time.** Only when I back out of this view and again navigate and load PersonTrackerView will it then start triggering. This appears to work on iOS17 beta, but not on iOS16.

Tried a number of different approaches, including referencing the UIViewPresentable within my SwiftUI view and then further inspecting during appear/disappear events.

Slight suspicion this might have something to do with the way it breaks down and deallocs but when I run this on a fresh install, this problem immediately occurs on iOS16.

Also, this happens:
"ARSession <0x10f133ce0>: ARSession is being deallocated without being paused. Please pause running sessions explicitly."

However this should be independent of the problem, since the above logs after I back out of SwiftUI.

**I even went as far as adding a killARSession() func in ARDelegate, but since this happens BEFORE this is ever called, seems unrelated.**

```
    func killARSession() {
        arSCNView?.session.pause()
        arSCNView?.removeFromSuperview()
        arSCNView = nil
        print("ARSession deallocated.")
    }
```

Comment: have you succeed? please share your exp